# I keep getting the error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'int *(__cdecl *)(int *,int *,int,int)' to 'int *

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error in the `c = sum_matrix` part.

> C2440  '=': cannot convert from 'int *(__cdecl *)(int *,int *,int,int)' to 'int *

This is the whole code (not finished though as i got stucked here):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>

void read_matrix(int*, int, int);
int* sum_matrix(int*, int*, int, int);

void main()
{
    int a[20][20], b[20][20], i, n = 0, m = 0, * p, * q, * c;
    printf_s("Enter the dimensions of the matrices: ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", n, m);
    p = &a[0][0];
    q = &b[0][0];
    read_matrix(p, n, m);
    read_matrix(q, n, m);
    c = sum_matrix;
}

int* sum_matrix(int* a, int* b, int n, int m)
{
    int *c, i, j, p;
    if (c = new int[n*m])
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                *(c + i * n + j) = *(a + i * n + j) + *(b + i * n + j);
    return c;
}

void read_matrix(int* a, int n, int m)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    printf_s("Enter the elements of the matrix (%d values): ", n * m);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf_s("%d", (a + i * n + j));
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 16.3.8

Comment: `cannot convert from 'int *(__cdecl *)(int *,int *,int,int)' to 'int *` - and why would you *expect* to be able to convert a function pointer to a pointer to int? Note: you are *not* calling the function. You are taking its address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum_matrix` is a function, you need to call it with parentheses like so:

`sum_matrix(a, b, c, d)`

Replace a,b,c,d with the arguments you would like to enter.

I think what you meant to do is this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>

void read_matrix(int*, int, int);
int* sum_matrix(int*, int*, int, int);

void main()
{
    int a[20][20], b[20][20], i, n = 0, m = 0, * p, * q, * c;
    printf_s("Enter the dimensions of the matrices: ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", n, m);
    p = &a[0][0];
    q = &b[0][0];
    read_matrix(p, n, m);
    read_matrix(q, n, m);
    c = sum_matrix(a, b, n, m);
}

int* sum_matrix(int* a, int* b, int n, int m)
{
    int *c, i, j, p;
    if (c = new int[n*m])
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                *(c + i * n + j) = *(a + i * n + j) + *(b + i * n + j);
    return c;
}

void read_matrix(int* a, int n, int m)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    printf_s("Enter the elements of the matrix (%d values): ", n * m);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf_s("%d", (a + i * n + j));
}
```

Comment: Oh yes. God,i can't believe what I did. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In main, you're assigning `c = sum_matrix` where `c` is an `int*`, whereas `sum_matrix` is a function with the signature `int* sum_matrix(int*, int*, int, int)`

Comment: Without the parenthesis `sum_matrix` is a pointer to a function. `c = sum_matrix;` means try to assign a pointer to a function to a variable that is a pointer to an int. I say try here because this is not a permitted operation.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit unclear. It is a pointer to a function and that has the signature shown in the error message (`int *(__cdecl *)(int *,int *,int,int)`).

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, `sum_matrix` is given no input arguments. It should be  `c = sum_matrix(a, b, n, m)`. Also, `c` should be declared as just an `int`, not a pointer to `int`(`int*`) .